# Jekyll: Using multiple .md files per directory and have them available as files, not sub-directories?

Tags: jekyll

I am looking for a way to have multiple markdown files (.md) in a directory and have them available as files (not sub-directories).

Example:

```
├── about/
|   └── index.md
|   └── history.md
|   └── vision.md
```

I want these to become urls like this (treated as files (no trailing slash))

```
base.url/about/
base.url/about/history
base.url/about/vision
```

instead of (directories (trailing slash)):

```
base.url/about/
base.url/about/history/
base.url/about/vision/
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Jekyll 3.x using [permalinks in your files front matter](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/). But, if you want to use this with Jekyll 2.4+ and Github pages, it seems that [there is a problem](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3809#issuecomment-167362127).

Permalinks with trailing slash are the way to go for now.